# prompting value to input field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, button, input

I have a simple html form with two input fields:

```
<form action="next.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="ini" />
    <input type="text" name="fine" />
    <input type="submit" name="next" value="next" />
</form>
```

Users input time strings to save starting time and end time of an event.
They can type in values where hours and minutes are separated by colon, comma or blank space, see `var parts` (for example 14:25, 18 05, 12,40).

To make things faster, I prompt automatically the end time, set 100 minutes later than the starting time (see `var totalm`).
The script below does that well.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="ini"]').change(function() {
$('input[name="fine"]').val(computeEndTime($('input[name="ini"]').val()));
});
function computeEndTime(ini){
var parts = ini.split(/[:,\s\.]+/).map(Number);
var hourstart = parseInt(parts.shift());
var minutestart  = parseInt(parts.shift());
var totalm = (hourstart * 60) + minutestart + 100;
var minutes = totalm%60;
var hours = (totalm - minutes) / 60;
return hours + ":" + minutes;
}
});
</script>
```

Now, I think it would be better to give users some more choice, so I want to provide 4 buttons, which add 50, 60, 100 and 120 minutes to the starting time (input "ini") and prompt it into the input field "fine".

Do you have any tips on any ways to accomplish that? The function I have works. I guess it is just needed to make the whole process `onclick` using buttons.

Comment: I would give users a place to `set default` and store it in localStorage so they don't have to set it each page load. Then use that for the calcs

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want a [timepicker](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-time-picker-plugins/) instead

Comment: Timepicker looks nice and handy, but using the keyboard to type in starting time and then pushing a button to set end time would be (in my view) faster.